# Regex match everything not in between

Tags: regex

So I have a text like e.g.

```
This is a text
+++ Everything in here shouldn't be matched +++
This should be matched
+++ This should neither +++
```

where i want to match everything that is not in between "+++" and "+++" (excluding "+++")

I figured how it could work with " instead of +++

```
.(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*\Z)
```

But I couldn't find out, how to do this with the "+++" as indicator.

Comment: `.(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*\Z)` is a very inefficient pattern, you should think of alternative approaches. What is your programming language? What is the final goal (expected output for the above string)?

Comment: Why not just remove everything between `+++` `+++` and what's left is your data?

Comment: What about `This line should be matched? +++` or `+++ This line should be matched?` and `What about +++ this one? +++`

Comment: For PCRE, you could try [`\+{3}.*?\+{3}(*SKIP)(*F)|.`](https://regex101.com/r/MKv5AI/1).

Comment: There is no specific Code, it's on KLWP (Android App), which offers a regex replace function (ox

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : just being curious. How did you learn regexen? Your code works, but I'm often not even close to understanding it, let alone write it on my own.

Comment: @EricDuminil: I started on my own long ago, .NET flavor. 2,5 years ago, I joined SO and have been here every day since then. That is how I learnt what I know.

Comment: @ChristianB: So, try `(\+{3}.*?\+{3})|.` and replace with `$1`. Not sure what "blank String" means though, if it is "empty string", this solution should help.

Comment: The result should be everything (including the +++), that is surrounded with +++.

Comment: I meant exactly what I wrote. But since the KLWP App can only use regex to replace strings I have to replace the strings I don't need (The text which is not surrounded with +++). The final, expected output is every line with +++anystring+++

Comment: So, have you tried `(\+{3}.*?\+{3})|.` (to replace with `$1`) yet?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this regex :

```
\+\+\+.*?\+\+\+
```

and replace it with an empty string. What's left is the text you're looking for :

```
This is a text

This should be matched
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/3qK5Pc/2)'s an example.

Comment: The thing is, I want to replace everything else with a blank String.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following to match every line that is not between `+++`

```
/^\w.*$/gm
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/zAoON1/2